# jVectormap adding markers from database only adds one marker

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, jvectormap

I am trying to add markers from a MySQL database via PHP into jvectormap (version 2.0.2).

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but when I add the markers dynamically using `.AddMarkers`, only a single marker shows up, which is the last marker in the JSON response.

This is my code:

**JavaScript:**

```
$("#airportsmap").vectorMap({
    map: "world_mill_en",
    scaleColors: ["#eff0f1", "#eff0f1"],
    normalizeFunction: "polynomial",
    hoverOpacity: .7,
    hoverColor: !1,
    regionStyle: {
        initial: {
            fill: "#6673a7"
        }
    },
    markerStyle: {
        initial: {
            stroke: "transparent"
        },
        hover: {
            stroke: "rgba(112, 112, 112, 0.30)"
        }
    },
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    markers:[]
});
function loadairportmarkers(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "modules/getfavouriteairportsdash.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,        
            success: function(response) {
            if(!response.errors && response.result) {
                $.each(response.result, function( index, value) {
                    addMapPoint(value[3], value[4], value[2]);
                });
            } else {
                $.each(response.errors, function( index, value) {
                    $('input[name*='+index+']').addClass('error').after('<div class="errormessage">'+value+'</div>')
                });

            }
        }
        })
}
function addMapPoint(lat, lon, title){
    var map = $('#airportsmap').vectorMap('get', 'mapObject'); 
    map.addMarkers([{ latLng: [lat, lon], name: title }], []);
}
```

**PHP**

```
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("
            SELECT .... query here
        ");
        $stmt->bind_param('is', $uid,$emp);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        while($row = $result->fetch_all())
        {
            $returnResult = $row;
        }
    }
    mysqli_close($mysqli);
    echo json_encode(['result' => $returnResult, 'errors' => $errors]);
    exit;
```

This results in the following JSON response:

```
{"result":[["HUEN","FAOR","Entebbe International Airport","0.042386","32.443501"],["GABS","FAOR","Modibo Keita International Airport","12.5335","-7.94994"]],"errors":false}
```

Comment: Maybe `map.addMarkers()` requires all of the markers in a single object array? Could you try compiling an object array in a loop, and then calling `map.addMarkers` once?

Comment: That was what i tried initially but it didn't work.

Comment: It might be worth adding your code for that into the question, and perhaps in the body text of the question you could expand on "didn't work". For example, what is the return value of `map.addMarkers` in each case - what do the docs say? Is it an "ok" value?

Comment: Also, your `map.addMarkers` as it stands is pushing two elements, not one - the second one is empty. Maybe, as another thing to try, remove that second element.

Comment: Finally, there may be some value in your creating a runnable HTML/JS sample in your question - the AJAX thing is probably a distraction, so break it down into a piece of code that does not need a database or an AJAX server. Just a map and adding, say, two points on it.